# Integrating two react functions in a synchronous way

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, synchronous

I have the React code below. I want integrate the handleUpdate into the handleUpload function in a synchronous way so that the state is set before the rest of the function is executed. I tried, the following below, with my edit in bold, but it appears to be executing asynchronously and not setting state before executing. Can anybody please instruct me where i need to make a change to meet my needs?

```
handleUpdate = event => {
   this.setState({
     selectedFile: event.target.files[0]
   })
}

handleUpload = () => {
  **this.handleFileChange;**
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file', this.state.selectedFile, this.state.selectedFile.name);
  fetch('/upload', {method: 'POST', body: fd})
      .then(response => {
          return response.json()})
      .then(result => {
           console.log(result)})
      .catch(function(error) {           
          console.log("ERROR:" + error);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
handleUpdate = event => {
  this.setState({
   selectedFile: event.target.files[0]
  }, ()=>this.handleUpload())
}
```

You can call the handleUpload function inside the callback function of setState, to make sure that the handleUpload function gets called only after the state.selectedFile is set

Comment: Works! Thank you